# How do you save your Activity's state when exiting? Android

Tags: java, android, save, multiple-instances

I have a basic app with text inputs, a spinner input, and a second spinner input whose array depends on a setting changed in the Options menu.

Currently, when I press Home or press Return while in my app, I either return to the desktop or cycle back through old inputs i put in recently.

How can I prevent my app from opening multiple instances of itself so that there is only one instance running at any given time, and then how can I save the data entered into inputs, and the settings chosen in my option menu?

I'm a bit new to Java, so I apologize if this is a simple problem.

Answer (score 5):

In your acticity override onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.  These methods will allow you to save data into a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)  You can also save data to [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).  In all of my applications I override both onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save and load values to a Bundle.  I also save data to preferences in onPause and load preferences in onResume.  Also in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) I do a check like this

```
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        m_mainView.restoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    else
    {
        m_mainView.loadGameFromDatabase(getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE));
    }
```

These practices have always worked for me.

Comment: Can  u provide me one sample example?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` is not called when the user explicitly exists the app by pressing back or home button. This can only be used when OS decides to destroy your activity without your intervention.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `onPause` overridden method on your activity and persist your data somewhere (shared preferences probably).
Then `onResume` you have to read them back from persistance storage and populate your controls.

`onSaveInstanceState` and `restoreInstanceState` is not your friend when you want to handle back or home button presses.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this also. I think these answers are great but could be narrowed down with some examples and more definitive information. For my example, my app is portrait only so I don't have to worry about saving for that but on return to home, even back button kills users text view data which is a garbage user experience. I have yet to find information describing what to do outside of screen rotate...