# getLastConfigurationInstance gives a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, configuration

I am trying to retain my Activity Configuration using

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array = alarmsArrayList;
    return array;   
}
```

And when i try

```
ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<String>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (data.size() != 0) 
    {
        alarmsArrayList = data;
        alarmList.setAdapter(adapter);
        startProgress(SingleAlarm.this.getCurrentFocus());
    }
    else
    {
        startProgress(SingleAlarm.this.getCurrentFocus());
    }
```

It gives a `Null Pointer Exception`.

Is there a way to retain every configuration of the Activity, like the CheckBox status?

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of ways to save configuration or states of views in Android. 
you can read this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

here is almost a same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667813/how-to-save-state-of-activity) asked.

or if you want you can create save views current state in database or shared preferences.